# The subnet does not exist error in terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I want to create elastic beanstalk with tf. Here is the `main.tf`

```
resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_application" "elasticapp" {
  name = var.elasticapp
}


resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment" "beanstalkappenv" {
  name                = var.beanstalkappenv
  application         = aws_elastic_beanstalk_application.elasticapp.name
  solution_stack_name = var.solution_stack_name
  tier                = var.tier

  setting {
    namespace = "aws:ec2:vpc"
    name      = "VPCId"
    value     = var.vpc_id
  }
  setting {
    namespace = "aws:ec2:vpc"
    name      = "Subnets"
    value     = var.public_subnets
  }
  setting {
    namespace = "aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:process:default"
    name      = "MatcherHTTPCode"
    value     = "200"
  }
  setting {
    namespace = "aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment"
    name      = "LoadBalancerType"
    value     = "application"
  }
  setting {
    namespace = "aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration"
    name      = "InstanceType"
    value     = "t2.micro"
  }
  setting {
    namespace = "aws:ec2:vpc"
    name      = "ELBScheme"
    value     = "internet facing"
  }
  setting {
    namespace = "aws:autoscaling:asg"
    name      = "MinSize"
    value     = 1
  }
  setting {
    namespace = "aws:autoscaling:asg"
    name      = "MaxSize"
    value     = 2
  }
  setting {
    namespace = "aws:elasticbeanstalk:healthreporting:system"
    name      = "SystemType"
    value     = "enhanced"
  }

}
```

I have variables defined in `vars.tf`.
This is the `provider.tf`

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "eu-west-3"
}
```

When I try to apply I get the following message

```
Error: ConfigurationValidationException: Configuration validation exception: Invalid option value: 'subnet-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' (Namespace: 'aws:ec2:vpc', OptionName: 'ELBSubnets'): The subnet 'subnet-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' does not exist.
│   status code: 400, request id: be485042-a653-496b-8510-b310d5796eef
│ 
│   with aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment.beanstalkappenv,
│   on main.tf line 9, in resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment" "beanstalkappenv":
│    9: resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment" "beanstalkappenv" {
```

I created the subnet inside the vpc that I provided in main.tf.

EDIT: I have only one subnet.
EDIT: adding vars.tf

```
variable "elasticapp" {
  default = "pos-eb"
}
variable "beanstalkappenv" {
  type = string
  default = "pos-eb-env"
}
variable "solution_stack_name" {
  type = string
  default = "64bit Amazon Linux 2 v3.2.0 running Python 3.8"
}
variable "tier" {
  type = string
  default = "WebServer"
}
variable "vpc_id" {
  default = "vpc-xxxxxxxxxxx"
}
variable "public_subnets" {
  type = string
  default = "subnet-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
}
```

Comment: Can you add the subnet code to the question as well?

Comment: Ok so you are not creating a subnet within the `main.tf` rather referencing an existing one?

Comment: yes, shuould I create one in main.tf?

Comment: It depends on your use case of course. But other than that, it does not seem there are any errors in your code. So you probably want to make sure you are in the right region, you are using the right VPC and last but not the least that there are not any typos in the default value you are assigning to the `public_subnets` variable.

Comment: Looks like vpc_id and public_subnets are assigned correctly. What should I check regarding the region? As far as I understand provider is the only attribute about the region. This is my first experience with tf so I'm not really sure.

Comment: Yes, you have defined the region in the provider block `"eu-west-3"`. Is the VPC in that region?

Comment: I don't find region attribute in vpc but when I try to create subnet in vpc it only allows to extend from eu-west-3. For example eu-west-3a, eu-west-3b. I guess that means that vpc is also in eu-west-3.

Comment: Yup, you can see the region in the top right corner of the AWS console when logged in.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so first, check if the error message is correct.

As mentioned above, there is a chance you are working in the wrong account/region.
So check if terraform can find that subnet by using a datasource:

```
data "aws_subnet" "selected" {
  id = var.public_subnets # based on your code above, this is a single subnet_id
}

output "subnet_detail" {
  value = data.aws_subnet.selected
}
```

If the above code fails, that means terraform is not able to use/find that subnet.
So, if the subnet was created by terraform there is a chance regions/alias/account got mixed on the way to this module.
If it was manually created and you are only using the ID as manually inputted string, than the chances are that you copied the wrong subnet_id, vpc_id or that you are working in the wrong account/region.

If the above return data, and terraform can indeed find that subnet, check if it belongs to the VPC you are using on elastic_beanstalk.
If all the above is correct, than the issue may by in the "aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment" definition.

As you have an ELBScheme but you don't have the rest of the fields related to that ELB it could be throwing an error.
Since ELBSubnets was not provided in the "aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment" definition, it may be trying to use a default subnet from the default vpc.